# No such table Sqlite error iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite

I am working with sqlite in iOS app. I have created login and register screens and tables successfully. Now, I am creating another table to save data. The table has been created but when I run the query to insert values, I get following error --- "no such table: proposalInfo". Can somebody help me in this ?

Comment: Obviously, the table has not been created.

Comment: Write your code how you make table and where you make it.

Comment: I have create table through terminal. and now trying to insert values in it when I get this error.

Comment: I agree with you. But I cannot describe my code in these comments. Can you please suggest an alternative for the same.

Comment: Yes, I have already checked these points and worked on it. but still the error persists.

Comment: I don't know how you can expect us to help you. Plain and simple, there either was an error creating the table or you're just accessing the wrong database. But we can't help further without seeing code. But I'd again ask you to consider the following scenario: Imagine some error in some earlier iteration of your app that failed to create table correctly and/or allowed `sqlite3_open` to create blank database (which is its default behavior). Once you have a blank database in Documents, does your code handle that properly?

Comment: @Rob - Hi Rob, I have posted a question related to AFNetworking , can you please help by providing the solution for that ? (Question header - AFNetworking version 3 content-type error)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you created database on terminal, then the problem is likely how you got the database you accessed from the terminal to your iOS device. Usually you would include it in the bundle (and make sure you have a checkmark against the appropriate target), and then you'd have code that looks for the database in “Application Support” directory, and if it does not find it, copy it from bundle to there. (Note, in the past, we would have recommended the “Documents” folder, but nowadays that is for user-facing files; we use “Application Support” directory nowadays for files used internally within the app.) The typical problem is simple bug in that logic (perhaps in previous iteration of development), which failed to copy it properly and then subsequently called `sqlite3_open` which created blank database.

Likely, somewhere in this process, there was insufficient error detection/reporting, so some error went undetected and blank database was created. So, I would recommend:

- remove app from device (to get rid of any blank database in “Application Support” folder, if any);
- double check error detection/reporting (e.g. check all `NSFileManager` method return codes and `NSError` objects);
- do not use `sqlite3_open`, but rather use `sqlite3_open_v2` so that it will never create blank database (namely, with `SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE` option, but *not* `SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE`); and
- run app again and see if you can identify where in the process it went awry.

---

By the way, if you do not believe us that the table is really missing from the database, I would suggest you open the simulator’s database from macOS SQLite tool, and simply confirm. So

- navigate to the simulator’s “Application Support” folder:

  > ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/[GUID]/data/Containers/Data/Application/[GUID]/Library/Application Support

  And
- Open that database in your SQLite terminal interface, and confirm existence or absence of the table in question.

Answer (score -1):

Please create table using SQLite browser. Which is you can download from [here](http://sqlitebrowser.org/). 
Then follow below step

**1) Open your project db by clicking.**

**2) Create table Query or using UI.**

**3) Execute query whatever you want.**